# How to Get list of all file under the directory by type in C

Tags: c, unix

I have to simulate the `ls` function of `unix` in `C`.

I have to create a program to "Get all files under any directory by type in C".

I googled and found programs which get lists of files, but they are alphabetically sorted; I want sorted by type of file.  Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Retrieve. Sort. Display.

Comment: Logic i know, but how i can sort, i directly printing file name in console, even if i store names in array, again i have to write some complicated logic to get types of file and then sort it, is there any better way or direct command for this.

Comment: I'm not sure why a file type would be complicated logic, but if it is, it is. I'm not sure if it's what you're asking for, but you can use `qsort` for the sorting point. Most of the simpler alternatives would involve some other language (e.g., Python or C++ with Boost.Filesystem)

Comment: so will plz tell me how to get type of file.

Comment: the 'type' or extension is just part of the filename...  parse off anything after the last . but it must come after the last /  ie path/to/file.extension vs path.to/file

Comment: What do you mean by type of file? Do you mostly care about file extensions (e.g., `.c` vs. `.cpp`), or permissions (is the execute bit set?) or what exactly?

Comment: "extension" is not the same as the "file type"! I may name my file "bild.jpg" but actually it could be a office document. ("man file" is a good startingt point)

Comment: You can start by looking at the [`opendir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* store the files somewhere in memory. Since this looks like a school project, I'd suggest to load the file names into a linked list, and employ one of the algorithms for sorting linked lists. This might well be the purpose of the exercise itself.

For `file type` let's assume "extension", i.e., a .MP3 is type "Fraunhofer MPEG Layer 3" even if somebody might have renamed a .WMA file and called it .MP3. To detect "true" file type you'd need to employ something called a "magic file", and there is a libmagic out there, but is it worth it? (If it is a doctorate thesis or a commercial program the answer is 'hell yes'. If the program is to be graded by your average professor, then you judge whether to risk being considered 'too clever').

The linked list entry ought to be a `struct` containing the file name and a pointer to its extension; this last you can find by considering that the extension is "whatever follows the last dot in the file name", so you can leverage the `strrchr` function. Remember that some files will have no extension.

You judge whether to employ a memory-saving hack such as storing the pointer to the extension, or duplicating the extension with `strdup`. The former is faster and leaner, but you must remember that the first struct pointer (filename) MUST be freed, and the second ABSOLUTELY MUSTN'T. Having two pointers behave differently might be considered bad coding practice (it is) or a clever hack (it is), depending on whether you value maintenance time or speed/memory.

As for the retrieval of file names itself, there's no all-portable way, so this has led to the development of libraries such as Boost. But for a school project, maybe you could restrict to POSIX systems and use `opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir` and `stat`.

A good practice and a wise thing to do would be to separate the operations (directory retrieval, list sorting, list display) in different functions, so that you can test them separately and incrementally (e.g.: the folder retrieval does retrieve everything and you can display the files in unsorted order, etc.).